# Python list with type strings

Tags: python, string, list, numbers, extract

I have got a python list

```
Year= [‘1997JAN’, ‘1997FEB’, ‘1997MAR’‘1997APR’………………………’2021SEP’’2021OCT’]
```

I would like to extract only years from the above list but not the months

How can I extract only years?

```
Year = [1997,1997,1997,…………………2021,2021]
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Year = [int(i[:4]) for i in Year]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have these dates:

```
dates = ['1997JAN', '1997FEB', '1997MAR','1997APR', '2022NOV']
```

Just use this to extract years from dates:

```
years = [int(x[:4]) for x in dates]
```

Comment: Probably should put in a int(  ) to convert to integers so that you match expected output from OP.

Comment: this solution won't work after 31-Dec-9999. But it won't be our problem anymore, so go ahead.

Answer (score 0):

You import and use the module `re`:

```
import re

Year= ['1997JAN', '1997FEB', '1997MAR','1997APR','2021SEP','2021OCT']

Years_only=[re.findall(r'\d+', year)[0] for year in Year]

Years_only
```

**Output**

```
['1997', '1997', '1997', '1997', '2021', '2021']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can first extract the numbers with `filter` and `str.isdigit` like this:

```
input = '1997JAN'
output = ''.join(filter(str.isdigit, input))
print(output)
# '1997' (This is still string)
```

Now we should cast it to integer:

```
output = int(''.join(filter(str.isdigit, input)))
print(output)
# 1997
```

You can do this in all elements in the list with map:

```
output = list(map(lambda input: int(''.join(filter(str.isdigit, input))), Year))
print(output)
# [1997,1997,1997,…………………2021,2021]
```